# What are the standard techniques\libraries used to determine the digital "image quality" of a facial image?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-detection

I'm working on a data set which has a good number of blurred, faded, dark, low resolution and noisy face images. I need to eliminate those images in the pre-processing stage, but I can't remove those images manually by subjective speculation.

Which libraries/APIs are used in the open source domain to evaluate the "quality" of the digital face images?

Answer (score 0):

The quality metric most used is mAP (median accuracy percent), where accuracy can be True Positives/Sample size or the jaccard index. So, you will need the ground truth for the dataset.